# UIScrollView flexible height

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I've got an UIScrollView in which there are an UIImageView and an UILabel, and they're both sizeToFit. How can I set the height of the UIScrollView autoresizing in base of the heights of the UIImageView and the UILabel?

Answer (score 0):

There is no such switch you can set in the interface builder. You will have to implement the following delegate method for your UITableView:

– tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:

Documentation for the method can be found here:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html

In this method you will have to access the frames of the respective row's contained elements. In your case the UILabel and UIImageView and calculate their combined heights from their frames.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Well, actually it's UIScrollView. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Do a loop in every subview of `UIScrollView`, and get the height of every items, then, set it to `ScrollView`, as:

```
int height = 0;
for(UIView *subview in [yourScrollView subviews]) {
   height += subview.frame.size.height;
}
yourScrollView.contentSize = CGRectMake(yourScrollView.frame.origin.x, yourScrollView.frame.origin.y, yourScrollView.frame.size.width, height);
```

I'm not sure that this will works, but it's a solution.

Hope this help.

Comment: This works presuming the UIImageView is on top of the UILabel, or vice versa--if they're next to each other, loop through to find the tallest item and use that as the height.  :)

Comment: That's what I was thinking. I'll try to find a solution. :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can find the scrollview height by using the following code

```
float height = 0.0;
for(UIView *subview in [yourScrollView subviews]) {
    if(height < (subview.frame.origin.y + subview.frame.size.height))
       height = subview.frame.origin.y + subview.frame.size.height;
}
yourScrollView.contentSize = CGRectMake(yourScrollView.frame.origin.x, yourScrollView.frame.origin.y, yourScrollView.frame.size.width, height);
```

Hope this will help you!

Answer (score 0):

```
yourLabel.frame = CGRectMake(0, 200, yourImageView.height, yourLabel.frame.size.height);
float heightOfScrollView = yourLabel.frame.origin.y + yourLabel.frame.size.height + 10;
scrView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(320, heightOfScrollView);
```

hope this help you....